# How to make enemy move toward player in Godot4 with C#

Tags: c#, game-development, 2d-games, godot4

I'm making a 2d top-down game in Godot 4 with C# and I can't get the enemy AI to move toward the player. The only time it follows the player is when the player in under the enemy and touching the enemy.

This is my code for the enemy movement:

```cs
public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
{
    Move();
    MoveAndSlide();
}

public void Move()
{
    if (_player != null)
    {
        LookAt(_player.GlobalPosition);
        Vector2 direction = (GlobalPosition - _player.GlobalPosition).Normalized();
        Velocity = direction * Speed;
    }
    else
    {
        Velocity = Vector2.Zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the value of `_player`?

Comment: _player = GetNode<CharacterBody2D>("Player");

Comment: When do you set the player is also important. Does he have to be in a specific line of sight, or do you atm just set him in the ready function?

Comment: I set him in the ready function

Answer (score 0):

The current direction you are calculating should make the enemy move away from the player, try switching `GlobalPosition - _player.GlobalPosition`:

```
Vector2 direction = (_player.GlobalPosition - GlobalPosition).Normalized();
```